# Windows 10 PRO: DBeaver + ODBC no connection

Tags: sql, jdbc, connection, odbc, dbeaver

I've an ODBC for 4D SQL connection correctly created on Windows manager:

[image]

which perfectly connects.

I have this very same connection up to 5 machines. All of them working without problems.

Then I install DBeaver with the common installations process: Next > Next > Yes > Next > ... Finish.

Then I create DBeaver connection with ODBC driver:

[image]

And as can be seen, perfectly connects and runs.
But this is where the problems begins. This very works on 4 of my 5 machines. Only on a server (Xeon machine) one, it doesn't.

This is the error I receive:

[image]

I commented on official DBeaver git forums, and they basically moved me away:

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/discussions/12612

I've tried to create a very simple Java code which connects through ODBC and compiled with JDK 7. If I run it trough Java JDK 7, it works and connects. But if I run with DBeaver emmbeded JRE or windows common installed Java JRE, it doesn't:

http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/JDBC-ODBC-DSN-Connection.html

So it really seems to be a Java problem, but then, why it works on all other machines but this one?
I do exactly the very same thing on every machine, same installation process, same configuration ODBC process. Copy.

But it doesn't works on this server.

DBeaver downloads 2 files always, ODBC.dll and the java_7_bridge. And they work everywhere, but here.

How to solve?

The error log on connection:

```
2021-05-13 19:05:10.440 - org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCConnectException: Unexpected driver error occurred while connecting to the database
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCConnectException: Unexpected driver error occurred while connecting to the database
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:227)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.generic.model.GenericDataSource.openConnection(GenericDataSource.java:135)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.connect(JDBCExecutionContext.java:101)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.initializeMainContext(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:100)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:59)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.initializeRemoteInstance(JDBCDataSource.java:109)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.generic.model.GenericDataSource.(GenericDataSource.java:107)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.generic.model.meta.GenericMetaModel.createDataSourceImpl(GenericMetaModel.java:90)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.generic.GenericDataSourceProvider.openDataSource(GenericDataSourceProvider.java:106)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.DataSourceDescriptor.connect(DataSourceDescriptor.java:897)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectJob.run(ConnectJob.java:70)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectionTestJob.run(ConnectionTestJob.java:103)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.initialize(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:453)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:153)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.lambda$0(JDBCDataSource.java:176)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:195)
... 13 more
2021-05-13 19:05:10.506 -
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.initialize(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:453)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:153)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.lambda$0(JDBCDataSource.java:176)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.openConnection(JDBCDataSource.java:195)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.generic.model.GenericDataSource.openConnection(GenericDataSource.java:135)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCExecutionContext.connect(JDBCExecutionContext.java:101)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.initializeMainContext(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:100)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCRemoteInstance.(JDBCRemoteInstance.java:59)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.initializeRemoteInstance(JDBCDataSource.java:109)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.generic.model.GenericDataSource.(GenericDataSource.java:107)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.generic.model.meta.GenericMetaModel.createDataSourceImpl(GenericMetaModel.java:90)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.generic.GenericDataSourceProvider.openDataSource(GenericDataSourceProvider.java:106)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry.DataSourceDescriptor.connect(DataSourceDescriptor.java:897)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectJob.run(ConnectJob.java:70)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.jobs.ConnectionTestJob.run(ConnectionTestJob.java:103)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Start Núcleo del equipo de soporte [org.eclipse.team.core 3.8.1100.v20200806-0621]
2021-05-13 19:10:03.725 - DBeaver is stopping
2021-05-13 19:10:03.726 - Stop RMI server
2021-05-13 19:10:03.727 - DBeaver shutdown completed
```

Comment: Support for the ODBC/JDBC bridge was removed from Java 8. You really need to contact DBeaver for support, as they know how they are setting things up for this. And also, if you want any help here, you will need to provide detailed error logs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark. The link I've posted to DBeaver forums, has all this information (DBeaver report logs).

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow need to be self-contained.

Comment: Up! Anyone? Stills the problem...